# Is there a way that a Party can be notified that a Flow has been completed?

Tags: corda

Taking as an example the flow described in the Corda documentation (see [here](https://training.corda.net/key-concepts/concepts/#flows)), how can Bob receive the notification that the transaction he just signed has been completed, without polling his own vault?
Does a specific callback exist?

I need that the CorDapp running on Bob node communicates to another system the status of the transaction in real-time

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Ashutosh's answer,

Inside a SpringBoot webserver that identifies an API to start your flow, you can use `proxy.startTrackedFlowDynamic()` (where `proxy` is your node's RPC connection); it returns a `FlowProgressHandle` which you can use to subscribe to flow events.

Comment: Thanks Adel for your further answer, at the moment we are working without a webserver, so your suggestion is not applicable in this specific context. We will keep in mind for any other future projects

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could achieve this:

**1. Subscribe to update using Client**

```
cordaRPCOPS.vaultTrack(<YourState>.class).getUpdates().subscribe( update -> {
            update.getProduced().forEach(stateAndRef -> {
                // Action to be Performed on State Update
            });
        });
```

**2. Subscribe to update using CordaService:**

```
getServiceHub().getVaultService().trackBy(<YourState>.class).getUpdates().subscribe( update -> {
    update.getProduced().forEach(stateAndRef -> {
        // Action to be Performed on State Update
    });
});
```